# Is there a way to prepopulate biblatex fields for some entries?

Tags: biblatex

When writing a `biblatex` style, Is there a way to prepopulate fields for some entries?

More specifically, the `bookpagination` field. The norms I have to follow require that I use "sheets" for theses, so I declared `sheet` and `sheets` bibliography strings and it works great. But it would be even better to have `thesis` entries use `sheet` for the `bookpagination` automatically if the user didn't fill in that field. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biber's sourcemapping is probably the easiest way. With `\pertype` it can even be restricted to certain types only, with `overwrite=false` we make sure that existing contents are not overwritten.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \pertype{thesis}
      \step[fieldset=pagination, fieldvalue={sheet}]
    }
  }
}
```